# extracting ideal string using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cut

I have the sample distro version:

`16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)`

I want to extract 16.04 from that. So I did:

```
if [ -f /etc/os-release ]; then
    . /etc/os-release
    echo $VERSION | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F. '{print $1$2}'
fi
```

Output is:

```
1604
```

But I want to have:

```
16.04
```

Comment: Try `awk -F"." '{print $1 "." $2;}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linux Standard Base tool `lsb_release -r -s` to get the distribution release number.

More info: `man lsb_release`

Answer (score 1):

Following simple `awk` may help you here.

```
echo "16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)" | awk -F"." '{print $1 FS $2}'
```

OR

```
awk -F"." '{print $1 FS $2}' your_file
```

Comment: Can't score + :(

Comment: @yasin, no issues when you have repo then you do it, BEST answer should be chosen always, cheers.